Garnir elements basic question
Prop. 2.6.3 in Sagan's book The symmetric group discusses Garnir elements, and says:
"If $|A\cup B|$ is greater than the number of elements in column $j$ of $t$, then $g_{A,B} \mathbf{e}_t=0$."
(As usual, $A$ and $B$ are subsets of the $j$th and ($j+1$)st columns of $t$, respectively, and $g_{A,B}$ is the Garnir element.)
Near the beginning of the proof, it says:
"Consider any $\sigma\in C_t$. By the hypothesis, there must be $a,b\in A\cup B$ such that $a$ and $b$ are in the same row of $\sigma t$."
I do not see why this is true. I can see that there must be $a,b\in A\cup B$ such that $a$ and $b$ are in the same row of $t$. But once we apply $\sigma$, don't we end up with $\sigma a$, $\sigma b$ in the same row of $\sigma t$, rather than $a,b$ in the same row of $\sigma t$? And then, $\sigma a$ and $\sigma b$ are not necessarily in $A\cup B$.
What elementary thing am I missing?

Just apply your reasoning to the subsets $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(B)$, instead of the subsets $A$ and $B$, of columns $j$ and $j + 1$ of $t$.  (They lie in those columns because $C_t$ is the column stabiliser of $t$.)

I've just spelt this out to the smallest detail a couple weeks ago: It's in the Proof of Lemma 5.8.4 in my An introduction to the symmetric group algebra.

@LSpice, Thank you but I am still confused. To continue the proof, we want to get to $S^-{A\cup B}{\sigma t}=0$, for which we need $(a,b)\in S{A\cup B}$ and not $(a,b)\in S_{\sigma(A)\cup \sigma(B)}$. So I'm still missing something...

Re, sorry, yes, on reflection, and for the reason that you say, my comment does not actually help with your question.

@darij Thank you Darij, what I needed is clearly explained in your lemma 5.8.6. Well-written! Lspice: The key (for me) is that in $\sigma t$, the elements of $A$ and $B$ are still in columns j and j+1 (this is related to what you wrote), but they'll be in different locations. Two of them must still be in the same row, but it may be a different row from the one for t. (I'm not a regular user of this site, so I don't know if elaborating on why I understood something is normal; I figured I'd tell you in case you were curious.)
